# Call React Component more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load various images in the DOM using React. My idea is to load in the same div all the images that I have on my database, so I tried using a for loop to call the react Component that renders the tags for the images tags, but, when the loop ends, the only image that is displayed in the DOM is the last one. Is there a way to do this using React ?

Here is my Component:

```
class CargarImagen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = '';
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-sm-3">
        <img
          src={this.props.ruta}></img>
        <a href="#">{this.props.name}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the function that calls that Component (the function **retornoDB** it's only an AJAX)

```
function clickListado() {
  retornoDB(function (data) {
    let json = JSON.parse(data);
    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#en_proceso');
    for (var key in json) {
      if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        ReactDOM.render(<CargarImagen ruta={json[key].ruta} name={json[key].nombre} />, domContainer);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render` is usually just for injecting the root of your app into a static div.  You are getting the last one only because you keep replacing that div with each of the `CargarImagen` components.  Instead, build up an array and return that to your the calling (parent) component's JSX.  You could place `myArray` in the component's internal state or just use a plain object and return that.  It's hard to tell what exactly how you're implementing it here.

```
for (var key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myArray.push(<CargarImagen ruta={json[key].ruta} name={json[key].nombre} />);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactDOM.render can handle array of components.

```
function clickListado() {
    retornoDB(function (data) {
        let json = JSON.parse(data);
        const domContainer = document.querySelector('#en_proceso');

        let Images = json.map((img, index) => <CargarImagen ruta={img.ruta} name={img.nombre} key={index}/>);

        ReactDOM.render(Images, domContainer);

    });
}
```